# App does not appear in iPad Settings list when iPad connected to Mac as external device

Tags: ios, photo

I am developing an iPhone/iPad photo processing app on a Mac using Swift in XCode 13.4. When I connect an iPhone running iOS 15.6 as an external device, the app appear in the Settings list and I can allow it to have access to Photos. When I connect to an iPad  running iOS 15.5 as an external device the program runs but fails when trying to access photos using info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset.rawValue]. This is commonly because permission to access photos has not been given to the app. When I tried to set this I found that the app did not appear in the Settings list. The app does appear in the iPhone settings list even though it has never been installed from the App Store.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why does the app not appear?

Comment: Ok, so what does "connect an iPhone running iOS 15.6 as an external device" mean? And why does it matter what an iOS device is "connected" to (whatever that means) if this is a question about an iOS app? It _is_ about an iOS app, isn't it?

Comment: I am developing an iOS app on a Mac. Many features require running on an actual device rather than a simulator. Connection is achieved by running a lead between the USB-C port on the Mac and the Lightning connector on the iPhone 8 (or the iPad)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so it turns out that you mean you're running from Xcode on the device. Good! But that is irrelevant to the question, as it turns out.

The question is why it is  that, on the iPad, there is no entry for your app in the Settings app, is that right? So that would be because on the iPad you've never done anything that causes the app to request permission (such as photos).

The point is, you cannot *initiate* the granting of permissions from Settings; the app itself must first request permission from the user (using the correct [PHPhotoLibrary call](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/3616053-requestauthorization)). Only after that happens will the app acquire a place in Settings where the user can modify the initial permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a programmatic definition of photo access options as suggested by Matt in main form viewWillAppear solved the problem as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_an_enhanced_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app. However, iOS 14 or newer is required.